# How to change color of the clock face and clock hand of time picker in Android

Tags: android, material-design, timepicker, material-components-android

How can the color of clock face and clock hand be customized in `TimerPicker`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version [1.3.0-alpha04](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.3.0-alpha04) of material design library,

> Adds default style attribute (`materialClockStyle`) to the time picker
> theme overlay for the clock face and clock hand, making all colors on
> the clock customizable.
> materialClockStyle respects the following attributes:
>
> - `clockFaceBackgroundColor`: color of the clock face
> - `clockHandColo`r: color of the clock hand
> - `clockNumberTextColor`: color of the numbers on the clock (CSL, selected state is used on top of the clockHandColor)